# timestamp wth timezone vs django

Tags: python, django, oracle, datetime, timestamp-with-timezone

My Oracle DB has a table with a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`. The Django model converts it to `datetime` but loses the original TZ info and assumes UTC.

DB:    `01-JAN-17 12.10.01.809000 AM -05:00`

Django:`2017-01-01 00:10:01.809000+00:00`

`USE_TZ = True`

The problem is that the table contains timestamps from different timezones. So if I change the standard timezone with `activate()` it won't help.

**Is there a way for Django to explicitly read the timezone from the database without assuming it?**

PS.: I'm aware that it would be better/easiest if my database would only contain UTC values but this is what I got.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem earlier, what i did was, I saved the time and timezone separately and used [pytz](https://github.com/newvem/pytz) and [tz_local](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tzlocal), which provides a timezone database and local timezone time respectively. While saving the time use one of these library to get the timezone and save time and timezone separately.